# How would I test for this line in Codeception

Tags: yii2, codeception

I am writing some unit tests and struggling to capture the 1 remaining line of this small model in Yii2.

**UserSearch.php**

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = User::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider; // This line in tests is red and marked as not executed
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'date_added' => $this->date_added,
        'last_login' => $this->last_login,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->username])

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

**UserTest.php**

```
public function testUserSearch()
{
    $model = new UserSearch();
    expect_that($model->search(['id' => 2]));
}

public function testInvalidDataProvider()
{
    $model = new UserSearch();
    expect_that($model->search(['id' => '2']));
}
```

The second test passes correctly as `!this->Validate()` method fails as id isn't an integer, why isn't the return statement reflected as executed in the code coverage. what am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Please show the code of `validate` method. `expect_that` is an odd assertion, what does it do?

Answer (score 2):

- Integer must contain only digits [see validation]: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/NumberValidator.php#L51 '2' is valid integer
- model->search() return ActiveDataProvider. Is correct.

Comment: Yes, I know, so the statement `if(!$this->validate())` correctly fails. So why isn't that reflected in the code coverage

Comment: You should uncomment this line // $query->where('0=1');